# rust macro expansion ignores token `,` and any following

Tags: rust, macros

this does work

```rust
macro_rules! x2 {
    ($x:expr) => {
        [$x, $x]
    };
}


let a = x2!(0)
```

but the quite similar

```rust
macro_rules! x2 {
    ($x:expr) => {
        $x, $x     //removed brackets
    };
}


let a = [x2!(0)]   //added brackets
```

does not and cancels expansion at the first seperator `,` with error:

```
macro expansion ignores token `,` and any following
the usage of `x2!` is likely invalid in expression context
```

- why is the seperator valid in one version and in the other not, they would unwrap to the same code?
- is there a way i could build something similar (to only fill part of the array like e.g. `let a = [x2!(1),0]`)?

  - would a declarative macro suffice?
  - if not, would that be a use-case for a procedural one?

---

i get that the working example produces an immediatly valid expression, while the latter only does in the context it's expanded in, but why does that matter? (the compiler already hints that the context might produce an invalid syntax but thats clearly not the case?)

Comment: To quote from my favourite resource on rust macros, the [Little Book of Rust Macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/introduction.html): "All syntax extensions in Rust **must** result in a complete, supported syntax element (such as an expression, item, etc.). This means that it is impossible to have a syntax extension expand to a partial construct.". Found in this section: https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/push-down-acc.html. Compile errors because of a badly expanded macro are horrible to debug, so I guess that is why Rust has this hygienic constraint.

Comment: thats exactly the reason/quote i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> i get that the working example produces an immediatly valid expression, while the latter only does in the context it's expanded in, but why does that matter?

To quote from my favourite resource on rust macros, the [Little Book of Rust Macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/):

> All syntax extensions in Rust **must** result in a complete, supported syntax element (such as an expression, item, *etc.*). This means that it is impossible to have a syntax extension expand to a partial construct.

Found in [this](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/push-down-acc.html) section of the book.

I assume Rust imposes this hygienic constraint on macros, because compile errors caused by badly expanded macros are horrible to debug, often times with unhelpful error messages.

Comment: This applies to procedural macros too, not only declarative ones, as the book says (_All_ syntax extensions).

Comment: Thanks @ChayimFriedman, I generalized my answer.